# meaning of 'renew' in the sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> In August 2013 **the Government of Canada renewed support of $100 million over seven years (2013-2020) for the Geo-mapping for Energy and Minerals (GEM) program**, which advances geological knowledge in the North to support increased exploration of natural resources and inform decisions on land use that balance conservation and responsible resource development.

What does *renewed* mean? Does it means that they decided to extend the period for supporting the GEM program which they have already been supporting? So they put $100 million from 2013 to 2020?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes to both questions.  Google research showed that Canada government already put $100 million for 2008-2013, and they are putting another $100 million for 2013-2020 (https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/resources/federal-programs/geomapping-energy-minerals/18215).  The usage of 'renewed' is thus correct.

Comment: Thank you for your helping me

Comment: You provide support and then you renew it, or not. :)